# How to extract parent value from XML when child element has a certain text

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, api, xml-parsing

I post to an api which returns xml showing the status of the orders i have posted. At the moment to get the warningcode and warning message this is what i have done and it works

```
Private Shared Function GetXMLElementValue(xml As String, element As String) As String
    Try
        Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Dim node = xDoc.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = element).FirstOrDefault()
        Dim nodeValue As String = ""
        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            nodeValue = node.Value
        End If
        Return nodeValue
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I call the above method like so

```
Dim warningCode = GetXMLElementValue(responseReceivedFromApi, "warningCode")
Dim warningMessage = GetXMLElementValue(responseReceivedFromApi, "warningMessage")
```

The above works fine when only a few orders were posted, however now I am posting 300 orders and it is proving difficult to find in which order the warning is raised.

e.g., the XML Returned

```
<order>
  <orderReference>148933</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>148955</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>148956</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
  <warnings>
    <warning>
      <warningCode>1116</warningCode>
      <warningMessage><![CDATA["Address is inaccurate"]]></warningMessage>
    </warning>
  </warnings>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>149025</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>149034</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
```

I would like to get the order reference (148956) where there is a warning. I am not sure how to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An option you could use is to create a function called `GetXMLElement` that will return the whole `XElement` instead of just a single value, then you could navigate its `Parent` property to find where it is attached to. For example:

```
Private Shared Function GetXMLElement(xml As String, element As String) As XElement
    Try
        Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Dim node = xDoc.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = element).FirstOrDefault()

        Return node
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

used as per:

```
Dim warningCode = GetXMLElement(responseReceivedFromApi, "warningCode")
Dim warningMessage = GetXMLElement(responseReceivedFromApi, "warningMessage")

If (Not warningCode Is Nothing) Then
    Debug.Print(warningCode.Parent.Parent.Parent.ToString)
End If
```

The `warningCode` elements parent is `warning`, the next parent is `warnings`. The last parent you are interested in is the `order` element

And, that will output:

```
<order>
  <orderReference>148956</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
  <warnings>
    <warning>
      <warningCode>1116</warningCode>
      <warningMessage><![CDATA["Address is inaccurate"]]></warningMessage>
    </warning>
  </warnings>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just getting the information you need in one shot as opposed to multiple calls. Along these line:

```
Dim orders As XElement = <orders>
<order>
  <orderReference>148933</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>148955</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>148956</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
  <warnings>
    <warning>
      <warningCode>1116</warningCode>
      <warningMessage><![CDATA["Address is inaccurate"]]></warningMessage>
    </warning>
  </warnings>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>149025</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
<order>
  <orderReference>149034</orderReference>
  <status>Updated</status>
</order>
</orders>


 Dim orderWithWarning = orders.Descendants("warnings") _
    .Select(Function(wr) New With { _
            .OrderReference =  wr.Parent.<orderReference>.Value, _
            .WarningCode = wr.<warning>.<warningCode>.Value, _
            .WarningMessage = wr.<warning>.<warningMessage>.Value _
            }).FirstOrDefault()
```

This returns an [Anonymous Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types)